# How can I delete repeating instances of words that exists in the same excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel spreadsheet has many duplicate values in single cells.  For example:

```
thisisA1thisisA1
andhereisA2andhereisA2
```

Is it possible to somehow count the characters and delete half of the value?  Or is there perhaps a better way to get ride of the repeated value.

It should read as:

```
thisisA1
andhereisA2
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)/2)`? Though I'm assuming this won't work in your actual use case.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, that seems to work perfectly!  Why did you think that it might not?

Comment: I thought your question might have over-simplified your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MID` or `LEFT` or even `RIGHT`, and `LEN`, dividing by 2:

```
=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)/2)
```

or

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/2)
```

or even

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)/2)
```